# Ошибка в запросе insert на postrgesql

Tags: postgresql, insert

Ошибка связана с полем description (тип данных oid). Что не так?

```
insert into public.production_studios(id,name,description,date_foundation) 
values ('1','Name','test','2022-08-14');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приложите схему этой таблицы, тогда станет ясно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно ошибка связана с тем, что тип данных "oid" принимает численные значения.

[image: Описание с официального сайта]